# How to list all newly created files in a specific directory?

Tags: java, file

What is the way to list files created, for example, between two timestamps? I'd like to list all newly created files and then move them to a different directory.

I'm working on Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void afterDate() throws IOException {
    final String pathToDirectory = "/path/to/directory";
    final long afterDate = new Date().getTime();
    final List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    final Path directory = Paths.get(pathToDirectory);
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(directory)) {
        for (Path path : directoryStream) {
            final BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
            final long creationTime = attr.creationTime().toMillis();
            if (creationTime >= afterDate) {
                paths.add(path);
            }
        }
    }
    for (final Path path : paths) {
        System.out.println(path.getFileName());
    }

}
```

Comment: You're mixing the legacy File API with the NIO.2 File API. Consider replacing File with Path.

Comment: Side note: URI is not needed for the local filesystem. You can use the Paths.get(String, String...) method.

Comment: @Puce, thanks again.. Removing `URI` makes me feel more at ease

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually watch out actively for newly created files, you can use a WatchService: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html

If you are only looking for the files that are there, you could, for example use the Apache Commons FileUtils class' [methods](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29) to list all files modified/create between two specific dates.

Answer (score 1):

The logic will be as below

Use a file class.

Iterate through all the files in the directory

It can be done using the **file.listFiles()** method.

The method will return all the files (files as well as directories) in the directory.

Then for each of the file object, get the timestamp using **file.lastModified()** and then check if it is between the timestamps you have specified

**startTimestamp < file.lastModified() < endTimestamp**